# GetEventLog - how to have 'Message' property expanded in one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In PowerShell v2 i'm using this cmdlet `Get-EventLog Security | Export-csv C:\file.txt` and get the following result.

**I need to get all information in one line. In my sample the 'Message' property is multiline.**

```
"538","MYPC","System.Byte[]","28330","Accesso/fine sess.","2","SuccessAudit","Fine sessione dell'utente:

    Nome utente:    myusername

    Dominio:        MYPC

    ID di accesso:  (0x0,0x58C702F)

    Tipo di accesso:    3
","Security","System.String[]","538","18/01/2013 10:35:54","18/01/2013 10:35:54","MYPC\myusername",,
```

I also tried with `Format-Table` but it truncate the Message field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` the fields you want to export and replace the `Message` field with a mangled version of itself:

```
Get-EventLog Security `
  | select EventId, ..., @{n='Message';e={$_.Message -replace '\s+', " "}} `
  | Export-Csv "C:\file.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried above.. multi line text getting into one line its hard to read.. trim worked perfect for my case.

```
Get-EventLog Security |
    Select EventId, ..., @{n='Message';e={$_.Message.trim()}} |
    Export-Csv "C:\file.csv"
```